# Android Background Image - Unwanted Horizontal Lines

Tags: android, background-image

My activity's background is showing up with some horizontal lines on both emulator and actual device that don't show up in the orginal image on my computer.

I am using GIMP to edit my background images. I have tried both .jpg and .png format.

Does anyone know why these horizontal lines are showing up?

The lines are hard to see from this emulator screen, but appear much more prominently on the actual device. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Star Fox 64]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the lines?

Comment: Quick thinking without having seen the problem first hand: Could it be from stretching? Multiple layout objects using the background as their own background? Like Jave said, please post a picture so we can get an idea of what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really hard to see the problem on the screenshot you posted, but it looks like it is compression related. You should check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417608/awful-background-image-quality-in-android/8417703#8417703).

Comment: Great! Your link was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of my answer but you should try to have a multiple of 2 for image's height and width.

Comment: The image dimensions are 480 X 800. I'm not quite clear on what you are saying.

Comment: This is quite unnecessary. If you are drawing in openGL or doing other specialised tasks this can be beneficiary, but not here.

Comment: Your picture's width and height are a multiple of 2. Sometimes when you use texture which are not a multiple of 2 you can experience problems like this. But you have picture of 480 x 800 so this is not the solution of your issue, sorry. =[