# image gradiente missing degrade

Tags: android, image, gradient

I have a image:

[image: backgorund degrade]

but in app it looks like this:

[image: background in android]

realize how degrading it loses, Why this ocurred? and how to I repair this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitmaps on ICS are loaded with wrong pixel format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097887/bitmaps-on-ics-are-loaded-with-wrong-pixel-format) The question may be not exact duplicate, but try to search here ["color banding"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+color+banding) and you will get answer.

Comment: There is [good article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/) on this topic by Romain Guy.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417608/awful-background-image-quality-in-android/8417703#8417703

Comment: @SergeyGlotov really there a good aticle thaks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417608/awful-background-image-quality-in-android/8417703#8417703)

and [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/) is good article on this topic indicated by [Sergey Glotov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436938/sergey-glotov)